# Android Studio marked my entire folder as project

Tags: android-studio

[image]

android studio marked my entire folder as project how can i remove it without losing apps inside project folder.

Comment: Why do you want to do so?

Comment: Choose just app folder

Answer (score 0):

Copy all the files of that project directory and move to a subdirectory.

While creating a new app you have selected the project folder wrongly. You have to manually remove all the application related files (i.e., .gradle, .iml, etc) from it.